# Doxygen and Fortran ENTRY

Tags: fortran, doxygen

Is Doxygen compatible with Fortran code (subroutines) using ENTRYs ? If it is, is there a special flag / something to do to make it so ?

This is the first time I'm using this software. it seems awesome, except CALLs to an ENTRY seem to be ignored, both for reference list generation and call graph generation.

Comment: for heavens sake get rid of that abomination. Either make duplicate copy of the sub starting at the entry point or introduce a logical structure to skip to the entry point.

Answer (score 2):

The Fortran implementation of doxygen does not support "ENTRY". The status: Declared obsolescent in Fortran 2008. Although doxygen does not (yet) all features of Fortran there are no plans to support this feature.

Comment: OK ; is there an alternative way to make it work ? Like by specifying an external preprocessor maybe (completely going out on a limb here) ? Alternatively, is another program able to do that (Sphinx, Ford, ...) ?

Comment: There are no alternative approaches known to me. Only thing to my knowledge is to convert to a more modern form of Fortran.